# Extension calls from an extension trigger rack warning

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, same-origin-policy

I've made a chrome browser extension that makes some simple get/post requests via JS to my sinatra server.
Every time a POST comes in, I see:

```
attack prevented by Rack::Protection::HttpOrigin
```

in the logs. The correct response is beint sent back.

I imagine it has something to do with browsers' Same origin policy, but I'm not exactly sure what is going on. Is it expecting a header that is missing?

Comment: Are you saying that a sinatra extension that is running on the server makes calls to itself - the extended application?

Comment: I'm sorry for an unclear explanation, I've edited the question. By "extension", I mean a browser extension

Comment: Try disabling a few of the things [listed in the docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Configuring%20attack%20protection) and see what you find and let us know.